# Error while importing scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am currently trying to install and run `scikit-learn`. Although I was able to get it to install, I get an error when I try and import `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`. What am I doing wrong?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
ImportError: No module named text
>>>
```

Comment: Please at least report your operating system name and version information information. Where did you get the scikit-learn package from, how did you install it and so on.

Comment: This would be unfair to close, as the OP is new and only trying to follow an old tutorial.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: python 2.7.5. I installed python 3 and it is working somewhat fine.

Comment: @SarathRNair is there a reason for not accepting my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I had to do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```

based on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599468/importerror-no-module-named-sklearn).